# ¿HashSet impide añadir objeto duplicados?

Tags: java

Me explico yo se que el HashSet no permite tener objetos duplicados pero no se si fuerzo en añadir si simplemente lo ignora. Tengo este método

```
public static Set ViviendasEntre2Precio(ObjectContainer db, int precio1, int precio2) {
    List<Vivienda> v = new ArrayList<>();
    int mayor, menor;
    if (precio1 > precio2) {
        mayor = precio1;
        menor = precio2;
    } else {
        mayor = precio2;
        menor = precio1;
    }
    for (int i = menor; i < mayor; i++) {
        Vivienda vivienda = new Vivienda(null, i, 0, null, false, null);
        ObjectSet res1 = db.queryByExample(vivienda);
        Vivienda vivienda2 = new Vivienda(null, i, 0, null, true, null);
        ObjectSet res2 = db.queryByExample(vivienda2);
        if (!res1.isEmpty() && res2.isEmpty()) {
            for (int x = 0; x < res1.size(); x++) {
                Vivienda vivienda1 = (Vivienda) res1.get(x);
                v.add(vivienda1);
            }
        }
        if (!res2.isEmpty() && res1.isEmpty()) {
            for (int x = 0; x < res2.size(); x++) {
                Vivienda vivienda1 = (Vivienda) res2.get(x);
                v.add(vivienda1);
            }
        } else {
            for (int z = 0; z < res1.size(); z++) {
                Vivienda vivienda1 = (Vivienda) res1.get(z);
                v.add(vivienda1);
            }
            for (int y = 0; y < res2.size(); y++) {
                Vivienda vivienda1 = (Vivienda) res2.get(y);
                v.add(vivienda1);
            }
        }
    }
    Set<Vivienda> hashSet = new HashSet<Vivienda>(v);
    v.clear();
    v.addAll(hashSet);

    return hashSet;

}
```

Prodria ahorrarme el primer List y añadirlo directamente a un HashSet y no me saldrian los duplicados o si fuerzo el añadido y se lo traga?

Answer (score 2):

Los Set usan el método equals de las instancias que introduces para encontrar duplicados. Si no sobreescribes ese método en tus clases, el set no será capaz de detectar si dos instancias son iguales. Asumiendo que tus elementos han implementado correctamente este método, entonces puedes usar un Set (HashSet, en este caso) para eliminar los repetidos.

Comment: Mi pregunta no es esa es si puedo envez de usar el List<Viviendas> un Hashset de viviendas y me sigue eliminando los duplicados

Comment: @unknow te sugiero que redactes mejor tu pregunta puesto que el título refiere a un tema y el cuerpo a otro. Por otra parte, esta respuesta si te resuelve tu problema. Para que un Set te elimine los duplicados debes implementar correctamente el método `equals()` en las clases de los objetos que agregas a este (en tu caso Vivienda)